# doubleloop vs numpy

Tags: gdal, loop, numpy

I would like to rewrite the following piece of code to use numpy, as it is too slow in its current format. The problem is that I cannot wrap my head around numpy to make it work

```
 pixels = band.ReadAsArray()
 list_dest = pixels.copy()

 for j in range(file.RasterXSize):
    for i in range(file.RasterYSize):
        if colordict[pixels[i, j]] == (231, 201, 101): list_dest[i, j] = 0
        elif colordict[pixels[i, j]] == (231, 241, 101): list_dest[i, j] = 1
        elif colordict[pixels[i, j]] == (234, 201, 101): list_dest[i, j] = 2
        elif colordict[pixels[i, j]] == (131, 201, 101): list_dest[i, j] = 3
```

Is it possible to rewrite it to use numpy.where? Or would the speed gains not be enought to compensate for the trouble?

Comment: What is the `colordict`?

Comment: @dmh126: it is a dictionary of colors (I am processing an image). If the pixel on that particular location of the raster has a certain value and the color of that value is blue, then I want to change the value of that pixel to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get keys from your colordict:

```
value_1 = (231,201,101)
number_1 = colordict.keys()[colordict.values().index(value_1)]
```

Than change values in your destination:

```
list_dest[np.where(list_dest == number_1)] = 0
```

And repeat it for each color you want, first get key from dictionary by value, than change all of values in destination with where.